# Why does jest doesn't understand ' assert { type: "json" } ' when importing json file in contract?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using typescript and the code works fine the problem is when I use jest to write test case if throws me error in one of the json file imports informing it doesn't understand " assert{ type:'json'} ". I can read json file using other ways also but using this it automatically understand the type which is helpful when using typescript.

import xx from '../src/configs/xx.json' assert { type: 'json' }

package.json

```
...
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
    "big-number": "^2.0.0",
    "ethers": "5",
    "icon-sdk-js": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.9",
    "ws": "^8.13.0"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/*"]
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.ts

```
import { type JestConfigWithTsJest } from "ts-jest";

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/default-esm", // or other ESM presets
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1",
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default jestConfig;
```

Does anybody has any idea how to solve the issue?

I tried using different version of typescript,
used different module name in compilerOptions, used different targets,
used other version of present to run jest.